# How to return a line from the action method in Struts2?

Tags: java, struts2, struts, struts2-jquery, actionresult

I want to return a line from the action method. My JSP is below

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <sj:head/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1">Div 1</div>
    <s:url id="ajaxTest" value="/test.action"/>

    <sj:a id="link1" href="%{ajaxTest}" targets="div1">
      Update Content
    </sj:a>
  </body>
</html>
```

**The action:**

```
@Action(value="test")
    public String jquery() throws IOException
    {
       System.out.println("hello");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Currently, I am getting the output as success and I think it's due to the return `SUCCESS`. What I need is to popup some custom text sent from the test action. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I think your action method needs to be mapped to jsp/template/view, you would also need to specify an object/model from which your view will be rendered.

Comment: can i do it by just getters and setters, will try n post back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classically to return something from the action you need to put the result annotation on the action or method

```
@Result(location = "/pages/success.jsp")
```

in the result you write the markup that will be inserted in the targets. You may need to supply http headers to turn off cache-control while the page is not reloaded.

Doing with the response you need your action to implement `ServletResponseAware`.

Comment: k. so i changed my action to @Action(value="test", results = { @Result(location="/jquery.jsp")
    })
    public String jquery() throws IOException
    {
       System.out.println("hello");
        return SUCCESS;
    }    now the result jquery.jsp is above code so its adding an extralink instead. See i used to write some text to response in a servlet and call that servlet from the jquery ajax. But how to do same in struts2, can i write some text in action method and get at client side? If so how to do that using struts2-jquery plugin. Thanks for your support

Comment: You can write to the response output in the action but then you need to return NONE result.

Comment: K thats done, your the boss :) last think is i want to get that text in a popup, the way my jsp is written(copied from google) I cant see any wat to get the response text, the text is being set to a div, I want the same in a popup, thankyou so much.